# vuetify: how to make v-data-table row blink when item values are updated

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js, css-animations

I would like to create a table that when items is updated, the row blink once.

i managed to make a row blink when the component starts, but it does not blink when value is updated.

i created an example with two css class (only for test), one that blinks once and another that blinks infinite.

if we update items values, we can see that the infinite still blinks and change rows as the condition is filled, but the items that should blink once, didn't change.

any help will be appreciated.

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.config.devtools = false;

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data() {
    return {
      items: [{
          id: 1,
          name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
          calories: 159,
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: 'Ice cream sandwich',
          calories: 237,
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          name: 'Eclair',
          calories: 262,
        },
        {
          id: 4,
          name: 'Cupcake',
          calories: 305,
        },
      ],
      headers: [{
          text: 'Dessert',
          value: 'name',
        },
        {
          text: 'Calories',
          value: 'calories'
        },
      ],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    blink(item) {
      if (item.calories > 200){
        return 'blink-great';
      } else {
        return 'blink-less';
      }
    },
    getRandomInt(min, max) {
      min = Math.ceil(min);
      max = Math.floor(max);
      return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
    },
    updateValues() {
      const newValues = this.items.map((el) => { 
        return {...el, calories: this.getRandomInt(100,500)}; 
      })
      this.items = newValues
    } 
  },
  computed: {
    displayItems() {
      var newItems = this.items.map((el) => { 
        return {...el, calories: el.calories * 1}; 
      })
      return newItems
    }
  },
});
```

```css
.blink-less {
  animation: blinking ease-out 1s 3;
  --background-color: #FF0000
}

.blink-great {
  animation: blinking ease-out 1s infinite;
  --background-color: #0000FF
}

@keyframes blinking {
  0% {
    background-color: var(--background-color);
  }
  100% {
    background-color: #fff;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-container>
      <v-row class="pa-5">
        <v-btn 
          @click="updateValues()"
        > Update value </v-btn>
      </v-row>
      <v-row class="px-5">
        <v-data-table 
         hide-default-footer 
         :headers="headers" 
         :items="displayItems" 
         :item-class="blink"
       />
      </v-row>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a flag and added new css classes.. it works but has poor code. If i found a better and clean solution i post it here

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.config.devtools = false;

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data() {
    return {
      controlAnimation: false,
      items: [{
          id: 1,
          name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
          calories: 159,
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: 'Ice cream sandwich',
          calories: 237,
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          name: 'Eclair',
          calories: 262,
        },
        {
          id: 4,
          name: 'Cupcake',
          calories: 305,
        },
      ],
      headers: [{
          text: 'Dessert',
          value: 'name',
        },
        {
          text: 'Calories',
          value: 'calories'
        },
      ],
    };
  },
  
  methods: {
    blink(item) {
      if (this.controlAnimation) {
        let itemClassTrue = 'blink-even-true'
        /* check item.value, based on condition...
        itemClassTrue = 'blink-less-true'
        itemClassTrue = 'blink-even-true'
        itemClassTrue = 'blink-great-true'
        */
        return itemClassTrue;
      } else {
        let itemClassFalse = 'blink-great-false'
        /* check  item.value, based on condition...
        itemClassTrue = 'blink-less-false'
        itemClassTrue = 'blink-even-false'
        itemClassTrue = 'blink-great-false'
        */
        return itemClassFalse;
      }
    },
    getRandomInt(min, max) {
      min = Math.ceil(min);
      max = Math.floor(max);
      return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
    },
    updateValues() {
      const newValues = this.items.map((el) => { 
        return {...el, calories: this.getRandomInt(100,500)}; 
      })
      this.items = newValues
    } 
  },
  computed: {
    displayItems() {
      this.controlAnimation = !this.controlAnimation
      var newItems = this.items.map((el) => { 
        return {...el, calories: el.calories * 1}; 
      })
      return newItems
    }
  },
});
```

```css
.blink-less-true {
  animation: blinking-less-true 1s 2 !important;
  --background-color: rgb(196, 76, 76) !important;
}

.blink-even-true {
  animation: blinking-even-true 1s 2 !important;
  --background-color: #fa0 !important;
}

.blink-great-true {
  animation: blinking-great-true 1s 2 !important;
  --background-color: rgb(3, 163, 70) !important;
}

.blink-less-false {
  animation: blinking-less-false 1s 2 !important;
  --background-color: rgb(196, 76, 76) !important;
}

.blink-even-false {
  animation: blinking-even-false 1s 2 !important;
  --background-color: #fa0 !important;
}

.blink-great-false {
  animation: blinking-great-false 1s 2 !important;
  --background-color: rgb(3, 163, 70) !important;
}

@keyframes blinking-less-false {
  0% { background-color: var(--background-color); }
  100% { background-color: #fff; }
}

@keyframes blinking-even-false {
  0% { background-color: var(--background-color); }
  100% { background-color: #fff; }
}

@keyframes blinking-great-false {
  0% { background-color: var(--background-color); }
  100% { background-color: #fff; }
}

@keyframes blinking-less-true {
  0% { background-color: var(--background-color); }
  100% { background-color: #fff; }
}

@keyframes blinking-even-true {
  0% { background-color: var(--background-color); }
  100% { background-color: #fff; }
}
@keyframes blinking-less-true {
  0% { background-color: var(--background-color); }
  100% { background-color: #fff; }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-container>
      <v-row class="pa-5">
        <v-btn 
          @click="updateValues()"
        > Update value </v-btn>
      </v-row>
      <v-row class="px-5">
        <v-data-table 
         hide-default-footer 
         :headers="headers" 
         :items="displayItems" 
         :item-class="blink"
       />
      </v-row>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not far off with `item-class`. It can take a string, which tells it to look for a prop on the item's object. With this, as you're updating the data, you can just add/remove the blink class to a prop you create on the fly.

In this case, I'm just going to name the prop `dynamicClass`

something like this:
template:

```
   <v-data-table 
     hide-default-footer 
     :headers="headers" 
     :items="items" 
     :item-class="dynamicClass"
   />
```

script:

```
  methods: {
    updateRandom() {
     const randomIdx = this.generateRandomNumber(0, this.items.length - 1);
     const randomNumber = this.generateRandomNumber(1, 1200);

     let item = { ...this.items[randomIdx] };
     item.calories = randomNumber;
     item.dynamicClass = "blink-less";

     this.$set(this.items, randomIdx, item);

     setTimeout(() => {
       delete item.dynamicClass;
       this.$set(this.items, randomIdx, item);
     }, 2000);
   },
   generateRandomNumber(min, max) {
     return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
   },
 },
```

The idea here is that we are adding & removing the class from the item/object in the array. doing it with `this.$set()` guarantees reactivity. But you could also use `Array.splice()` but either way, you want to replace the data object at that index to maintain reactivity.

Here is a working example in a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/stack-v-data-table-blink-on-new-data-o8unmc?file=/src/components/Playground.vue)